# Print special character from utf-8 encoded string

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having trouble dealing with encoding in Python:

I get some strings from a csv that I open using pandas.read_csv(), they are encoded in unicode so I encode it to utf-8 doing the following

```
# data is from my csv
string = data.encode('utf-8')
print string
```

However, when I print it, i get

```
"Parc d'Activit\xc3\xa9s des Gravanches"
```

and i would like to return

```
"Parc d'Activités des Gravanches"
```

It seems like an easy issue but I'm quite new to python and did not find anything close enough to my problem.

Note: I am using Python 2.7 and my file starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# coding: utf8
```

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ` at the beginning of your code and retry

Comment: @Nuageux this won't solve anything - it only tells Python how to handle string litterals with the module.

Comment: I already have

    `# coding: utf8`

which works the same, i stil tried with -*- but it didn't change anything

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3 ?  How is your file opened ? And please post the exact code where you "print" your string.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just say that you are using Python 2, okay, I think the answer below is still valuable though.

In Python 2 this is even more complicated and inconsistent. Here you have `str` and `unicode`, and the default `str` doesn't support unicode stuff.

Anyways, the situation is more or less the same, use `decode` instead of `encode` to convert from `str` to `unicode`. That should fix it.

More info at: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

---

This is a common source of confusion.The issue is a bit complex, but I'll try to simplify it. I'm talking about Python 3 here, I believe there's several differences with Python 2.

There's two types of what you would call a string: `str` and `bytes`.

`str` is the general string type form Python, it supports unicode seamlessly in Python 3, but the way it encodes the actual data is not relevant, it's an object.

`bytes` is a byte array, like `char*` in C. It's a sequence of bytes.

Strings can be represented both ways, but you need to specify an encoding standard to translate between the two, as `bytes` needs to be interpreted, because it's just, again, a raw array of bytes.

`encode` converts a `str` into `bytes`, that's the mistake you make. Of course, if you print `bytes` it will just show it's raw data, AKA, the string encoded as utf-8.

`decode` does the opposite operation, that may be what you need.

However, if you open the file normally (`open(file_name, 'r')`) instead of in byte mode (`open(file_name, 'b'`), which I doubt you are doing, you shouldn't need to do anything, printing `data` should just work as you want it to.

More info at: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Do you know the name of the argument you're passing so I can look in the doc whether I can apply this to pandas.read_csv()?
I'm thinking of things like `'index = '` or `'header = '`

I just found out that once passed to my data frame, it gets printed correctly if I print it from the data frame which is what I want to do in the end so it is not really an issue for me anymore but I would be curious to find out.

Comment: Even if the issue is solved, it could be interesting if you took the opportunity to learn it. I have edited my post with Python 2 info.